# How can I generate classes from wsdl that work at design time in Visual Studio?

Tags: mvvm, wsdl, expression-blend

I'm doing MVVM with model classes that are generated using the visual studio wizard for "Add Service Reference".

I'm trying to generate some design time sample data that will appear in the designer.

The problem I face is that collection members don't get initialized, so I changed this line of generated code:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
private System.Collections.Generic.List<SDDM3.HylandService.ServiceKeyword> KeywordListField;
```

to this:

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
private System.Collections.Generic.List<SDDM3.HylandService.ServiceKeyword> KeywordListField = new System.Collections.Generic.List<ServiceKeyword>();
```

After doing that the designer in VS didn't complain.

I realize these changes will be lost when I re-generate the code.

Is there some way to tell the code generator to do this for me?

Comment: If you are using "Add Service Reference", then you're using the same technology as svcutil.exe, not the technology of wsdl.exe.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks, I've edited the title and tag accordingly.

Comment: See if you can do that initialization in another part of the partial class, especially if no constructor has been generated - you can create a constructor in another class part, that won't be touched by code generation.